# Windows 10 not recognizing second monitor plugged in Onboard Graphics

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

My motherboard is a **M5A78L-M PLUS USB3**, from ASUS. It have a port for a VGA monitor, and I have a monitor connected to it (this is the secondary monitor).

I also have a **Nvidia Geforce GTX 960** video card, and it has a monitor connected to the DVI port onto it (this is the primary monitor). This video card doesn't have a VGA port, and the secondary monitor can't be plugged in this card.

When I boot Windows, everything is displayed on the Primary Monitor, and I'm not able to use the secondary monitor for anything. It's not recognized when trying to select my displays.

On Device Manager, the monitor isn't recognized at **Monitors**, and at Display Adapters, there's only NVIDIA Geforce GTX 960.

This doesn't work in Linux also. If it could work in both OS, it would be great, but focus here is Windows.

What can I do to use my secondary monitor along my primary monitor?

Comment: When only booting into off the VGA screen, do you get display? I know traditionally you *shouldn't* but I have "fixed" issues this way.

Comment: My understanding is that at a time only one graphic card is active in a desktop. So only the monitors connected to your Nvidia card will work. If you remove your card, then the VGA monitor will work

Comment: @ThisIsNotMyRealName I didn't understand

Comment: @GaneshR. It used to work before, with this video card and another onboard. But since I formatted my PC and changed motherboards, it stopped working

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: Can you describe the previous system configuration under which displays plugged into the given ports functioned simultaneously? (Like @GaneshR., I've never seen this work before...)

Comment: Does the cpu support onboard graphics? If so remove the GPU and try to start from onboard graphics, then add the GPU again, hope this helps.

Comment: Normally onboard graphics gets disabled by the bios when there is a GPU installed.

Comment: Have you installed your driver from the [NVIDIA Driver Downloads](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)?

Comment: @user3.1415927 I don't remember the specs, but I could set my BIOS to not disable the Onboard graphics, and then I could use both screens.

Comment: @Alex it does. But I'm not able to use both Onboard graphics and GPU

Comment: @harrymc Yes. I have the latest drivers from NVIDIA

Comment: I suggest to get an HDMI-to-VGA adapter and put both monitors on the GTX. These adapters are cheap enough. That's the way that things were designed to work, and anything else is strong-arming the operating system to do something that it doesn't do well.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking your UEFI settings.sometimes there is an option named iGPU - multi monitor or similar,under chipset settings so that when you have a PCIe GPU the onboard graphics get disabled.

1)Check UEFI settings,try making onboard as primary

2)Check iGPU and discrete are working properly ( through device manager)

3)I wouldn't reccomend any VGA - HDMI adapters since analog to digital and reverse usually doesn't work very well ( in my experience at least)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use the on-board display card in parallel with the GTX 960
is not a configuration that is easily supported by Windows.
There might be a way of making it work, but I don't know of one.

On the other hand, the GTX 960 is designed to support up to four monitors
in parallel, which is a configuration that is well-supported by Windows.

If the problem is just that the GTX 960 does not have a VGA port, geting an
[HDMI-to-VGA adapter](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_11?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hdmi-to-vga+adapter&sprefix=HDMI-to-VGA%2Caps%2C244&crid=JYX8INYR3N99)
in order to put both monitors on the GTX is a cheap solution,
starting from $7 on Amazon.
That will solve your problem without any
manipulations of Windows (which might not exist).

Below is an example of
[one adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016HL4CAY)
that has today 3,942 extremely positive customer reviews on Amazon:

[image]

Comment: Slightly more expensive as it would require two adapters, but it might be better to move things around to use a VGA-DVI adapter and plug the secondary monitor into the DVI port and get a DVI-HDMI adapter to plug the primary monitor into the hdmi port. If the primary monitor supports DVI-D (or DVI-I) and the graphics card supports DVI-A (or DVI-I) this will avoid having to convert between digital and analog via an adapter